# JavaScript Regular Expression Help: Validating Phone Number but excluding 555 numbers (match this, but not that)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working with a CMS that includes the ability to build forms, and uses JS validation for those forms.  We can replace the existing validation rules with our own Regex if desired.

Currently, the regex in place for Phone Number fields is:

> ^(1\s*[-/.]?)?(((\d{3}))|(\d{3}))\s*[-/.]?\s*(\d{3})\s*[-/.]?\s*(\d{4})\s*(([xX]|[eE][xX][tT]).?\s*(\d+))*$

This works okay, but we'd also like to exclude numbers that have a 555 for the area code OR exchange.  While these are technically numbers that conform to the phone number spec, the decision makers would like them filtered out since they're usually not "real" numbers.

I'm not enough of a Regex guru to understand how to deal with a "match this, but not that" sort of expression.  Can anyone offer any advice/assistance?

Thanks!

Comment: It probably isn't worth your time to exclude those numbers. By doing so (and by having such a strict regex in the first place), you are already excluding _most_ of the world outside the U.S. I would suggest you _lower_ your barrier to entry, especially if these forms are used to make money in _any_ way.

Comment: If you're asking multiple questions, "Is this a phone number?", "Is this a '555-' number?" then I'd separate that out into separate (commented) lines of code rather than build a gargantuan, unreadable regular expression. `isPhoneNumber(str) && !startsWith('555', str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a negative lookahead with `(?!555)`. Put it right after the `^(1\s*[-/.]?)?`. It w

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where "area code" or "exchange" parts are in the phone number, but all you have to do is add a negative lookahead before the relevant part.

This, for instance, will match three digits except 555: `(?!555)\d{3}`